# undefined is not a function: unit testing passport authentication custom callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, passport.js

I'm new to passport and express and trying to get a better idea of how everything works together by creating unit tests for all of my code.  I have been having good success but today ran into an issue I don't quite understand...

I'm attempting to unit test the following exported function on `session.js`:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
passport = require('passport');

exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) return res.json(401, error);

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {

      if (err) return res.send(err);
      res.json(req.user.userInfo);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

I seem to be having trouble with the second to last line (req, res, next) and how/when it gets called.  I also have never seen this type of call in Javascript where the last line is just a set of parameters.

In order to test I'm using [rewire](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rewire), sinon, and mocha.  In my test I'm using rewire to change the passport dependency to a mock object that I control.

My test seems to be working as expected as evidenced by where it is failing and what instanbul is telling me is covered but it alwasy throws: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

If I comment out the **(req, res, next)** line in `session.js` then my test actually runs successfully.

My test `session.unit.js`:

```
'use strict';

var rewire = require('rewire'),
should = require('should'),
sinon = require('sinon'),
sessionController = rewire('../../../../lib/controllers/session'),
passportMock = {};


describe('Session Controller', function() {

  describe('#login', function(){

    beforeEach(function(){
      sessionController.__set__({
        'passport': passportMock
      });

    });

    it('should return 401 status and error if passport authentication returns error', function(){
      //given
      var res = {
          json: sinon.spy(),
          send: sinon.spy()
        },
        req = {
          logIn: sinon.spy()
        },
        next = sinon.stub();

      passportMock.authenticate = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(1, 'ERROR', null, null);

      //when
      sessionController.login(req, res, next);

      //then
      res.json.calledWith(401,'ERROR').should.be.true;
    });

  });

});
```

My questions are:

1. What is the last line (req, res, next) used for and when is it called? (I suspect middleware)
2. Is there a way I can change my test to get it to pass without the undefined error?

Thanks very much for reading and any help you can provide!!

** **EDIT:** **
I think I left out a critical piece of information...  This `session.login` function is called from my `routes.js` file so I believe the last line is needed for middleware to continue.  I'm still confused as to how to allow this to continue processing in the unit testing though.

`routes.js` snippet:

```
  app.route('/api/session')
    .post(session.login)
    .delete(session.logout);
```

** **EDIT2:** **

Added the top part of `session.js` for clarity on how passport is initially declared with `require`.  In the unit test I am replacing passport via rewire with my mock (stub) object so that I can control what passport returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help, but this is generally how I stub passport.authenticate when used in the same way you have.

```
var stub = sinon.stub(passport, 'authenticate').returns(function() {});
stub.yields(new Error('fails here'));

// add your tests here

stub.restore();
```

Comment: Stephenmuss, thanks for the help, this mostly did the trick.  The key was that the stub needed to return something and I was not doing that, I was only invoking the callback.  My final line looks like:

`passportMock.authenticate = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(1, null, null, 'INFO').returns(function(){});`

This allows the callback to be invoked as I expect while also returning an empty function per middleware requirements.  

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. The `})(req, res, next);` towards the end of your session.js is unnecessary because of how scoping rules work in JavaScript and because `passport.authenticate` does not return a function (it probably returns nothing which by default returns undefined), so that is the reason for the error.
2. Just change the `})(req, res, next);` from the end of session.js to just `});`.

Comment: thanks for the answer!  I tried updating my code by removing the line but my e2e tests started failing waiting for /api/session to return. I updated my question above with the relevant routes.js snippet, let me know if that changes anything.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you define your passport variable. your code calls for it passport. and if undefined you get precisely that error. Also check the order of your middleware. Passport should be after session because it injects that req.logIn() and other stuff into your session.

Comment: Biba, thanks for looking.  I added some statements that may have gotten formatted out of my original question.  I am using rewire to inject a mock passport object and stub its return call.  The ordering of middleware should not affect this due to it being a test although I could be mistaken.

Comment: Still I don't see where you declared your "local" authentication strategy. You are calling authenticate but I don't see the strategy declared at all. To baseline your error, it says you're calling a method of a null object, meaning something that's not defined or that method doesn't exist, generally a sign the injection didn't happen and passport didn't see the express session defined to inject itself into.

Comment: Hi Biba, that is actually my intention.  I am trying to completely replace the `passport.authenticate` call with my own stub.  My statement in the test: `passportMock.authenticate = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(1, 'ERROR', null, null);` is telling my class under test to call the authenticate callback (arg 1) with 'ERROR' so that I can simulate an authentication exception.

Comment: you need to define and declare the strategies. after that you can call authenticate and request a specific strategy that IS implemented in your code. I think you need to study passport implementation a bit. it's a lot of polymorphism in there.